# Delphi Indy SSL crash when aborting

Tags: delphi, indy

When I read a webpage with delphi, using TIdHTTP with thet GET method, and when I abort the socket via the Disconnect function, or when into trigger an exception, and its establishing a ssl connection at that moment, it will just crash.

I have the following lines in the exception log and have no idea what might cause it and maybe soembody experienced the same and can give me some hints what could cause it.

It does not happen on my PC, but on a couple of users PC's, so its hard to find the issue. The 2 ssl dll's are the same I use, both are version 1.0.2.3

```
1107b239 +009 libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_OBJECT_free
1108520f +05f libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_primitive_free
1108550c +08c libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_template_free
110854cf +04f libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_template_free
1108550c +08c libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_template_free
1108552c +00c libeay32.dll                                     ASN1_item_free
11081b0a +00a libeay32.dll                                     X509_free
1202a433 +083 ssleay32.dll                                     SSL_SESSION_free
1202787c +0ec ssleay32.dll                                     SSL_free
007b66ce +04a sblinkextractor.addon.exe IdSSLOpenSSL           TIdSSLSocket.Destroy
00408cbc +008 sblinkextractor.addon.exe System        478   +0 TObject.Free
007b4d1b +023 sblinkextractor.addon.exe IdSSLOpenSSL           TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Destroy
```

Comment: Are you calling `Disconnect()` across thread boundaries? Possibly related to [Access Violation in SSL_accept() when deactivating TIdTCPServer](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/218),where the underlying issue is `Disconnect()` closing the `IOHandler`, which then destroys SSL objects that may still be in use. Try calling `TIdHTTP.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket()` instead. Raising an exception within a `TIdHTTP` event handler should be OK, though.

Comment: But why does your trace log mention `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Destroy`? `Disconnect()` doesn't destroy the `IOHandler`, only `Close()` it.  Who is destroying the `IOHandler`?

Comment: At the start of the thread, I dynamically create an instance of TIdHttp, TIdCookieManager, TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdSocksInfo. Then Indy trigger an exception, which I catch with try/except/end and then release the 4 created objects before I exit the thread.

Comment: that scenario is perfectly fine under normal conditions, and should not be crashing. But you say you are aborting the socket, how and where are you doing that exactly?

Comment: I abort in the onWork event via Disconnect. In the thread, I do a TIdHTTP.Get, which trigger an exception due to the Disconnect, which I catch via try/except/end. Because I know something went wrong, I release the mentioned instances of TIdHTTP etc. via their Free function and exit the thread.

Comment: in that case, I would suggest not calling `Disconnect()` in the `OnWork` event, just have it raise an exception instead, such as by calling `SysUtils.Abort()`, and let `TIdHTTP` close the socket for you